# Java Generics: incompatible type required String; found: java.lang.String

Tags: java, generics

I'm getting this compiler error in netbeans:

incompatible types
  required: String
  found:    java.lang.String

I'm kind of lost as why this happens?

Code:

```
private class StringIterator<String> implements Iterator<String> {

    private Iterator<Entry<K, byte[]>> i = internalMap.entrySet().iterator();

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return i.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        return decompress(i.next().getValue());// error on this line
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: plz provide more information regarding your imports & decompress() that will help us to help u...

Comment: Change `StringIterator<String>` to simply `StringIterator`. Also, you're not showing the `K` type parameter, the declaration of `internalMap` or the signature of `decompress`, all of which would be most useful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should remove the type argument from the StringIterator class. This is causing the compiler to consider any occurrence of String in the class to be a generic type rather than java.lang.String.

```
private class StringIterator implements Iterator<String> {
```

Comment: thanks.This was the solution. I'm new to at creating my own generic classes.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Ouch. Good catch. +1 - my reply is now obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

What are your imports? Did you maybe import the "wrong" `String`? Plus, what is `decompress`?

Update: see other reply, which has the correct answer. You named your generic "String". Remove the generic you don't use.

Answer (score 1):

What is decompress? If it is a method, then it must also return String.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to supply another situation where this can occur as it was stumping me for a while. The solution gkamal stated is correct.

In my case, I had the following:

```
public class NodeLabelTransformer<V, String> implements Transformer<V, String>
{
....
}
```

but I was receiving the error.

```
@Override
public String transform(V s)
{
   StringBuilder label;
   label = new StringBuilder();
   label.append("MyLabelText");
   return (label.toString());
}
```

In this case the solution is that my class should be declared as:

```
public class NodeLabelTransformer<V> implements Transformer<V, String>
{
```

I just wanted to point out, that the parameters of the Transformer interface are still the same, but my class declaration differs.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases,when your imports doesn't include **import java.lang.String**, you get this error.

Comment: All classes under `java.lang` are always automatically imported.
Here, the problem comes from a misuse of `StringIterator`'s generic type `String` which shadows the class `java.lang.String`